# How integrate correctly Ant Design with next.js? Link not works

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, antd

I am trying to integrate ant-design with next.js like the example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design-less, it works but when I click on a Link to a page that uses any antd component, it doesn't work and when I click on a Link to a page that doesn't use any antd component, it works. Can I help me please ?
I create a codesandbox with my problem https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-ant-design-8t41c

Answer (score 0):

The Next.js `<Link>` component comes with the `<a>` functionality. Including an `<a>` tag inside the `<Link>` will cause errors.

Read the [Next.js Link documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating) to learn more.